# "ImportError: No module named 'tastypie'" when running "django-admin migrate"

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm getting the following error stack when trying to issue a "django-admin migrate" command:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/django-admin", line 21, in <module>
    management.execute_from_command_line()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
  utility.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 87, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import     
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load  
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2224, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'tastypie'
```

When a run `pip list`, `django-tastypie (0.12.1)` is listed.
Anyone knows why django cannot find this module?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you added `tastypie` to `INSTALLED_APPS ` in `settings.py`?

Answer (score 1):

Add `tastypie` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in your project's `settings.py` file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (   
    ...   
    ...
    'tastypie',   
)
```